# What exactly is "check_nrpe_1arg"?

Tags: nagios

I see in a lot of the Nagios documentation references to `check_nrpe_1arg`.

Can anyone explain exactly what this is, or does?  I see nothing in the Nagios documentation, or anywhere else on the web, that comes right out and says "`check_nrpe_1arg` does __".  At best, it's "you need `check_nrpe_1arg` here", but without explaining what or why.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen that before. Have some links?

Comment: @VxJasonxV, for numerous links Google check_nrpe_1arg

Comment: Three steps ahead of you :). Note the timestamps on both this comment and my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Based off a quick cursory search, check_nrpe_1arg is nothing special compared to check_nrpe, it has a bit of a backstory too.

check_nrpe by default does not accept command line arguments to be sent, just the command_name to run on the remote NRPE server host. In order to get NRPE to accept arguments beyond that (if memory serves), you have to enable a compile-time definition, AS WELL AS configure it in check_nrpe as well as the NRPE server `nrpe.cfg` file.

check_nrpe_1arg appears to be a mnemonic that is configured into the core NAGIOS `commands.cfg` file; specifically, telling the installer that this command will accept only 1 argument (the name of the command to execute on the remote host) and will not honor any additional arguments.

It's a weird way to do it, given the default behavior of NAGIOS, but it gained traction nevertheless.

The quickest answer to this:
`check_nrpe_1arg` does exactly what it is configured to do in `commands.cfg` on the core NAGIOS server. In this context, it provides the command name to execute on the remote NRPE server, and nothing additional will be accepted.

[edit]
Also, it appears to have originated out of the default configs in "Untangle" (a Linux based firewall/routing software package), that or Debian, it's hard to tell without following a handful of links around.

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer this as far as Debian distributions go (at the time of wheezy)... check_nrpe_1arg is a command name defined in /etc/nagios-plugins/check_nrpe.cfg.

check_nrpe accepts the name of the nrpe command to run on the remote host along with arguments (space separated) to pass to the remotely executing command. check_nrpe_1arg, by contrast, only accepts the name of the command to run on the remote host (i.e., no arguments are passed to the remotely executing command).

check_nrpe_1arg is useful if you have hard-coded a very specific command on the remote host and wish to call it without passing it any parameters. An example of this you sometimes see is check_hda1 or check_sda1 which is defined in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg. check_hda1 and check_sda1 are hard-coded commands that call check_disk with specific parameters.